# Calling a variable from another page in php

Tags: php

I have such a loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($dersler);$i++)
{
   echo $dersler[$i].', ';
}
```

I want to run this loop on another page by capturing $dersler variable from another page. How can I manage it?
Thank you.

Comment: I have tried "global", but it didn't work.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the variable as a query parameter and access it again using the [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) superglobal. An other option is posting the variable to the page using a form, and accessing it through [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

But the solutions mentioned above require sending the value to the client side where it could be modified. If this is not desired, you could use a session to store a value serverside, between requests from the same client. Take a look at the session documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php.

Comment: Thanks. I'm making a review.

Answer (score 0):

You can store $dersler in a session.

on the first page :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['dersler'] = $dersler;
```

and on the other page :

```
session_start();
$desler = $_SESSION['dersler']; 
for($i=0;$i<count($dersler);$i++){
    echo $dersler[$i].', ';
}
```

Comment: I'm trying now :) Thanks.

Comment: be careful, the session_start() have to be called before any echo or html tag. Usually, the session_start() is the first line on a page ;)